# Minkowski spacetime light cone

Tags: linear-algebra

> In special relativity, light rays in Minkowski spacetime $\mathbb{R}^n$ travel
>   along the light cone which, by definition, consists of all null
>   directions associated with an indefinite quadratic form $q(x) = x^TKx$.
>   Find and sketch a picture of the light cone when the coefficient
>   matrix K is
>
> a.) $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$
>
> b.) $\pmatrix{1&2\\2&3}$
>
> c.) $\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1}$

I don't even know where to begin. This chapter deals with positive definites and it gives this question.

Comment: Do you know what "null direction" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null vectors are, by definition, vectors of length zero. This length is measured by the norm associated with the quadratic form: $\sqrt{Q(v)}$.

So, null vectors will be the $x$ such that $x^T K x=0$.

Comment: So, I will solve the matrices given and let them be homogenous, which then gives me the answer necessary to draw the light cone?

Comment: If by "let them be homogeneous" you mean "set $x^TKx$ equal to $0$", then I suppose so. Really, all of that is implicit in "*solve $x^TKx=0$*.